# Need help with CANbus protection

Tags: capacitor, capacitance, protection, can, tvs

Made a circuit to protect the CANbus on picture 1, but still have a couple of questions. Should i add filter capacitors on the CANH and CANL lines like in the second picture? In circuit on picture 1 i have a TVS diodes with 30 pF capacitance. I did not add capacitors to the circuit because I thought that 30 pF would be enough (my decision was also influenced by the documentation I read; I read that there should not be more than 35 pF of capacitance on the line). If I should add capacitors to the circuit, what value should I take? Should I change something in the circuit?

[image] Picture 1.

[image]

Picture 2.

Comment: What transceiver are you using and why do you need external TVS? What's your transient protection requirement?

Comment: @Lundin  At a minimum the external ESD protection is going to increase the range of CAN transceiver parts which can be used.  That's important with the semiconductor shortages this day and age.  If one is concerned about cost, one can leave the TVS unpopulated.  So, external TVS is the right idea, even if the CAN transceiver already has some built-in ESD protection.  [Береженого Бог бережет.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev Well sure, except TVS diodes might be just as hard to find as CAN transceivers currently, so now you have 3 parts you can't buy instead of 1  :) And well I wouldn't specify anything which doesn't handle the regular ESD requirements 15kV air 8kV contact, because some old CAN transceivers could handle that way back.

Comment: @Lundin  You didn't get it.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yes I get it that TVS can be mounted optionally. But if you have specified a subpar transceiver then that's not an option. Actually I just now went back to check the datasheet of the good old MCP2551 and it only has 6kV contact on the CAN lines. Which is still probably fine without external TVS in many applications. I used that one in industrial applications without external TVS, just common mode choke, never had any problems.

Comment: @Lundin  Don't specify *a* CAN transceiver.  Specify *a range* of CAN transceivers; a lot [majority] of CAN transceivers are pin-compatible.  That increases the probability of finding parts at any given time.  If you can make do with external TVS and less of built-in ESD protection, that increases the probability even further.  Sum of probabilities.

Comment: @NickAlexeev Yeah but unfortunately even the most common SO8 ones are compatible only to a certain point, the pin 5 tends to come with special behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with your approach.
If it is not for CAN-FD 5Mbps you may not need additional capacitors as the TVS will filter a bit.
in STM [ESDCAN01-2BLY](https://www.st.com/en/protections-and-emi-filters/esdcan01-2bly.html), they give the S21 (attenuation) curve of the TVS :
[image: S21 attenuation curve of SOT23-3L ESDCAN series]

You can check the filtering profile of each CAN protection versus their capacitance value.

If you implement CAN-FD, then maybe you should select a lower capacitance CAN protection to be sure not to degrade the signal integrity. You'll have more details in this [doc](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/sales_and_marketing/presentation/product_presentation/group1/f5/c2/2e/77/08/25/45/b8/CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series/files/CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CAN-bus-protection-ST-ESDCAN-series.pdf).

Cheers

Answer (score 4):

Common mode chokes are not always needed. Place one if you **really** need to - remember that this depends on the quality requirements (e.g. EMC for automotive, railway, etc. -- specifically immunity requirements), and operational test results such as running the unit in a noisy environment (e.g. industrial). And make sure that the one you plan to use is **specifically for CAN applications** i.e. you can't use a random CMC. There's no such indication on the datasheet of the CMC shown on your schematic. WE's ACT45B series, and Murata's DLW43SH and DLW32SH series have some CMCs suitable for CAN. You might want to have a look (this is not an advertisement).

TVSs should have small capacitance as possible as you don't want to load the lines with higher capacitance so that the pulses don't lose their shape (i.e. soften the edges).

I can't say anything about "max 35pF" thing. Most of the CAN xceivers already have about 30~50pF input capacitance, and these capacitances will interact with the CMC so normally you don't need to place any external capacitors across the CANH-GND or CANL-GND.

Comment: Indeed, suitable CMC parts will be advertised as "for CAN bus". Here's [Murata's recommendations for automotive](https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/emc/emifil/cmcc/pdf/automotive-signal.ashx?la=en&cvid=20220216010000000000) (feel free to add it to your answer). Indeed DLW43MH from the question appears suitable for Ethernet and the CAN part is supposedly DLW43SH. I've been using it's older cousin DLW31SH for many years.

Answer (score 3):

It all depends on the product/circuit you are designing. Normally there are no additional capacitors needed on the CAN lines. That does not mean you should completely ignore them. If in case of EMC certification you might want to add these capacitors. Again you should be watchful about the values as they could harm your communication reliability.
Good luck!